# Ajax type POST y enviar a dos php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

tengo un formulario de reserva en un restaurante y requiero que llegue la información de la reserva al restaurante y un mensaje de que la reserva fue recibida por el cliente.  Tengo dos archivos php, cada uno envía por separado los correos, pero cuando lo hago juntos no me funciona, ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal y cómo lo soluciono?  Este es el código:

```js
//Formulario de contacto movil
$("#fomulariollamada_mov").submit(function (event) {
    // cancels the form submission
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#enviando_mov").removeClass("d-none");
    submitForm_mov();
});


function submitForm_mov() {
    // Initiate Variables With Form Content
    var nombre = $("#Nombre_mov").val();
    var tel = $("#NumeroTelefono_mov").val();
    var email = $("#CorreoElectronico_mov").val();
    var mensaje = $("#Motivo_mov").val();
    var personas = $("#Personas_mov").val();
    var fecha = $("#Fecha_mov").val();
    var hora = $("#Hora_mov").val();
    var ampm = $("#AmPm_mov").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../php/contacto.php",
        data: "name=" + nombre + "&email=" + email + "&tel=" + tel + "&mensaje=" + mensaje + "&personas=" + personas + "&fecha=" + fecha + "&hora=" + hora + "&ampm=" + ampm,
        success: function (text) {
            if (text == "success") {
                formSuccess_mov();
            } else {
                console.log("Error de PHP. No retorna Success", text);
            }
        }
    });
}

function formSuccess_mov() {
    $("#enviando_mov").addClass("d-none");
    $("#msgSubmit_mov").removeClass("d-none");
    $('input[type=text],input[type=email],input[type=tel],textarea,input[type=number],input[type=date],input[type=time],select').val('');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../php/cliente.php",
        data: "name=" + nombre + "&email=" + email + "&tel=" + tel + "&mensaje=" + mensaje + "&personas=" + personas + "&fecha=" + fecha + "&hora=" + hora + "&ampm=" + ampm,
        success: function (text) {
            if (text == "success") {
                console.log("Enviado al cliente", text);
            } else {
                console.log("Error de PHP. No retorna Success en cliente", text);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

```css
body{background-color: #ffffff;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:cover}body #menu-licores{height:40px} body img{margin-top:50px;width:80vw}body .btn-outline-primary{background-color:#ffffff;border-color:black;color:black}body .btn-outline-primary:hover{border-color:#ffffff;background-color:#5eb800;color:#ffffff;-webkit-box-shadow:10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);box-shadow:10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75)}.modal-header{background-color:#5eb800;color:#ffffff;height:70px}.modal-header h3{font-size:20px;font-weight:700}.modal-body{background-color: #f1f1f1;} input, textarea{font-size:14px}#enviando_mov,#contenedor-fechahora{color:#f1f1f1;background-color:#000000;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);border:0}#msgSubmit_mov{font-size:13px}.d-none{display:none !important}.close{color:#ffffff}.close:hover{color:#5eb800}#form-submit:hover{background-color:#ffa500;color:#ffffff;-webkit-box-shadow:5px 5px 2.5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);box-shadow:5px 5px 2.5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.8)}#seleccion-motivo p{color:#f1f1f1;background-color:#000000;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5)}#seleccion-motivo select{color:#484848}@media (min-width: 576px){body img{margin-top:120px;width:70vw}}@media (min-width: 768px){body img{margin-top:150px;width:60vw}}@media (min-width: 992px){body{background-image:url(../imagenes/fondopc.jpg)} body img{margin-top:100px;width:20vw} body .btn-outline-primary{background-color:transparent}}@media (min-width: 1800px){body .btn-outline-primary{font-size:25px;font-weight:700;padding-left:30px !important;padding-right:30px !important;border-style:inset;border-width:2px}body .btn-outline-primary:hover{border-style:solid;border-width:0px}}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body class="text-center container-fluid">
                        <form role="form" id="fomulariollamada_mov" class="px-2 px-md-5">
                            <div class="form-group mb-1 mt-3">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control border border-primary border-0 pl-4 ml-0" id="Nombre_mov" placeholder="Nombre" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group mb-1 mt-3">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control border border-primary border-0 pl-4 ml-0" id="CorreoElectronico_mov" placeholder="Email" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group mb-1 mt-3 row pl-3">
                                <input type="tel" class="form-control border border-primary border-0 pl-4 ml-0 col-7 mr-2" id="NumeroTelefono_mov" pattern="[0-9]{10}" title="Número celular (10 digitos) sin espacios" placeholder="Teléfono" required>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control border border-primary border-0 ml-0 col-4" id="Personas_mov" pattern="[0-9]{10}" title="Número de personas" placeholder="#Personas" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group mb-1 mt-0 row pl-3" id="seccion-fechahora">
                                <div class="col-11 ml-1 row" id="contenedor-fechahora">
                                    <p class="m-0 p-0 pb-1 col-5"><b>Fecha:</b></p>
                                    <p class="m-0 p-0 pb-1 col-6"><b>Hora:</b></p>
                                </div>
                                <input type="date" class="form-control border border-primary border-0 pl-4 ml-0 col-5 mr-2" id="Fecha_mov" pattern="[0-9]{10}" title="Número celular (10 digitos) sin espacios" placeholder="Fecha" required>
                                <input type="time" class="form-control border border-primary border-0 ml-0 mr-2 col-3" id="Hora_mov" pattern="[0-9]{10}" title="Número de personas" placeholder="Hora" required>
                                <select class="form-control col-3" id="AmPm_mov" required>
                                    <option value="am">am</option>
                                    <option value="pm">pm</option>
                                </select>

                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group mb-1 mt-0 pb-2" id="seleccion-motivo">
                                <p class="m-0 p-0 pb-1"><b>Motivo de la reserva:</b></p>
                                <select class="form-control" id="Motivo_mov" required>
                                    <option value="Cena de amor y amistad">Cena de amor y amistad</option>
                                    <option value="Aniversario">Amigos</option>
                                    <option value="Aniversario">Aniversario</option>
                                    <option value="Cita Romántica">Cita Romántica</option>
                                    <option value="Cumpleaños">Cumpleaños</option>
                                    <option value="Despedida">Despedida</option>
                                    <option value="Grado">Grado</option>
                                    <option value="Negocios">Negocios</option>
                                    <option value="Otro">Otro</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class="alert alert-light my-0 p-0 d-none" role="alert" id="enviando_mov">
                                <p><strong>enviando...</strong></p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="alert alert-success d-none" role="alert" id="msgSubmit_mov">
                                <strong>¡Bien hecho!</strong> Tu mensaje se ha enviado exitosamente. <strong> &nbsp;Pronto te contactaremos.</strong>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group text-right mt-1">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn" id="form-submit">Enviar</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: A qué te refieres con enviarlos juntos? Porque por lo que veo en tu código siempre envías los dos ya que primero haces el "submitForm_mov" y en el success de este llamas al otro "formSuccess_mov".

Comment: Lo que estoy haciendo es quitarles las clases que ocultan el mensaje de "enviado con éxito" y oculto el mensaje que aparece de "Enviando"

Comment: Pues no debería fallarte lo que veo, puede ser la versión de jQuery? El success está deprecated y en su lugar deberías usar done http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: No he entendido bien lo que quieres hacer, pero en vez de intentar dos envíos desde el cliente, ¿por qué no lo haces desde el servidor? Es decir, desde `contacto.php` llamas o incluyes a `cliente.php` y haces lo que tengas que hacer. No tiene sentido esa ida y vuelta al servidor. Si recorres 500 km a por un paquete, ¿volverías a recorrer los mismos 500 km por un segundo paquete? ¿Por qué no lo trajiste en el 1er viaje teniendo espacio en tu vehículo?

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario, pero la verdad no se como hacerlo.  Creo que también podría hacer el envío de dos correos desde el mismo archivo .php con distintas variables pero no lo he logrado.  Si alguien tiene un link con información o algún ejemplo agradecería mucho.